# What loop can I use to iterate so that I can get the following output?

Tags: python, loops

This is my code.

```
def split_routes(routes_data):
    first_station = routes_data[0] #(’171’, ’1’, ’1’, ’59009’)
    curr_ser = first_station[1] #171
    for entry in routes_data:
        ser = entry[0]
        a = filter_routes(routes_data,"first_station[1]") # [(’171’, ’1’, ’1’, ’59009’), ... , (’171’, ’2’, ’73’, ’59009’)]
        x = tuple(["first_station[1]"] + [a])
        c = []   
        return c.append(x)
```

filter_routes is previously defined

```
def filter_routes(routes_data, service_code):
    data = filter(lambda entry: entry[0] == service_code,
     routes_data)
    return data
```

`print(filter_routes(bus_stations, "106")`  will return

```
[('106', '1', '1', '43009'), ('106', '1', '2', '43179'), .... ('106', '2', '51', '43009')]
```

I know it is wrong as my output should be when i `print(split_routes(bus_stations))`
This should be the output.

```
[(’171’, [(’171’, ’1’, ’1’, ’59009’), ... , (’171’, ’2’, ’73’, ’59009’)]),
 (’106’, [(’106’, ’1’, ’1’, ’43009’), ... , (’106’, ’2’, ’51’, ’43009’)]),
  (’184’, [(’184’, ’1’, ’1’, ’45009’), ... , (’184’, ’1’, ’52’, ’45009’)])]
```

routes_data = bus_stations here is a txt file that look like this

```
106,1,1,43009
.
.
.
106,2,51,43009
171,1,1,59009
.
.
.
171,2,73,59009
184,1,1,45009
.
.
.
184,1,52,45009
```

Comment: can you add the input you use (`routes_data`) so we can check our answers?

Comment: and we don't know what `filter_routes` do.

Comment: @Elisha I have already edited it. So sorry, the routes_data should be the bus_station.txt and I define filter_routes already. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like your problem is that you use `"first_station[1]"` as a string and not use its value.
try call
`filter_routes(routes_data,first_station[1])`
and
 `x = tuple([first_station[1]] + [a])`
in addition, you use only your first station, I thing you meant to use `ser` value, and another problem is that you return and quit the function before you finish, store the values in variable like `resultz here, and return it when you finish:

```
result = []
for entry in routes_data:
        ser = entry[0]
        a = filter_routes(routes_data,ser) 
        x = tuple([ser] + [a])
        result.append(x) 
return result
```

**However I would write it this way:**

```
def split_routes(routes_filename):
    stations = {}
    with open(routes_filename,"r") as routes_data:
        for line in routes_data:
            vals = line.strip().split(",") # [’171’, ’1’, ’1’, ’59009’]
            stations.setdefault(vals[0],[]).append(vals)
    result = []
    for st in stations:
        result.append((st,stations[st]))
    return result
```

and call it with the filename:

```
split_routes("bus_stations.txt")
```

Comment: thank you for the comment. But then how do I do a loop such that I am able to get the output ??

Comment: Yes It works now. I did the spliting and forming of the list bus_stations.txt before doing this questions!! But thank you so much :) I finally know my mistake ! But just a question why do u put result = [ ] before the for loop ?? Why can't u put it in the for loop itself ??

Comment: I need one instance of `results` list so I created it once, if I would create in in the loop I would get instance for each iteration.
in each iteration I just add value to `results` list, and when the loop finish, I return the list with all the values

Comment: is it possible that you help me with this as well [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22326280/making-a-loop-to-form-a-list

Answer (score 0):

Here is one snippet that you can adapt for your use -

```
import fileinput

station_routes_map = {}

for line in fileinput.input():
    route = line.strip().split(',')
    first_station = route[0]
    if first_station not in station_routes_map:
        station_routes_map[first_station] = []

    station_routes_map[first_station].append(route)

output = [(key, value) for key, value in station_routes_map.items()]
```

This basically stores the output that you desire in the output variable. You can adapt it for your function. Might need a fix here and there, since I haven't tested it, but overall it should run.

### UPDATE

Ok, let me explain. The file you have is in the format -

first_station, .....rest_of_the_route....

What you are looking for, is a list of tuples that have first station as the first param, followed by the list of all routes that begin with that first station.

What this code does is -

1. uses the fileinput module to read from your file, from command line (let's say)
2. splits the line on ',', and uses the first nibble as first_station
3. the station_routes_map dictionary is used to store the first_station as a key, and a list of routes as its value.
4. for every line, it figures out the first_station and then add the route to an appropriate list in the station_route_map (using first_station as the key)

After building the map, it just uses list-comprehension to prepare a list of tuples from the dictionary by iterating over all its items.

Comment: I am a little confuse with your solution as I am not sure where does fileinput come from. And why station_routes_map[first_station] = [] ??? Also what if first_station is in station_routes ??

Comment: I have edited the code above maybe this is clearer now :) Thank you

Comment: What is station_routes_map = {} ?? Sorry I just started learning python

Comment: ok, i have updated the answer with explanation for the code. hope it helps.

Comment: Do you mean this ??                                                    return map(lambda y: [] , x)

Comment: oh, I think I caused the confusion because of the word map. My bad. I didn't mean the map(...) function in python. I meant a dictionary. station_route_map is a dictionary variable name. I come from c++ background, and end up with that terminology quite often. Sorry for the confusion.