# Making a loop to form a list?

Tags: python, loops

```
def make_services(routes_data):
    routes = []
    curr_route = []
    x = split_routes(routes_data)
    service_data1 = x[1]  # (’106’, [(’106’, ’1’, ’1’, ’43009’), ... , (’106’, ’2’, ’51’, ’43009’)])
    service_data = service_data1[1] #[(’106’, ’1’, ’1’, ’43009’), ... , (’106’, ’2’, ’51’, ’43009’)]

    first = service_data[0]  #('106', '1', '1', '43009')
    service_code = first[0]
    curr_dir = first[1]   # '1'
    l = list(curr_dir)    # ['1']


    for entry in service_data:
        direction = entry[1] #'1'
        stop = entry[3]  #'43009'

        if direction == curr_dir:   
            curr_route.append(stop) #[43009]
        else:
            routes.append(curr_route)   #[[]]
            curr_route = [stop]         #['43009']
            curr_dir = direction       #not '1'
            l.append(direction)  # ['1', __]


    routes.append(curr_route)   #[['43009']]

    #modi
    return [(tuple([service_code] + [l] + [[curr_route]]))]
```

Basically my code only return me

```
[('106', ['1', '2'], [['43009', ... '43009']])]
```

However what i need is

```
[ ('106', ['1', '2'], [['43009', ... '43009']]),
     ('171', ['1', '2'], [['59009'...'59009]]),
      ('184', ['1'], [['45009'... '45009']]) ]
```

x = split_routes(routes_data) returns me

```
[(’171’, [(’171’, ’1’, ’1’, ’59009’), ... , (’171’, ’2’, ’73’, ’59009’)]),
(’106’, [(’106’, ’1’, ’1’, ’43009’), ... , (’106’, ’2’, ’51’, ’43009’)]),
(’184’, [(’184’, ’1’, ’1’, ’45009’), ... , (’184’, ’1’, ’52’, ’45009’)])]
```

I believe that there is something wrong with my loop on top... Should there be 2 loops ?? And a hint was given is that I could use map.

routes_data here is bus_stations.txt

```
106,1,1,43009
.
.
.
106,2,51,43009
171,1,1,59009
.
.
.
171,2,73,59009
184,1,1,45009
.
.
.
184,1,52,45009
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something more like:

```
def make_services(routes_data):
    output = []
    for service in split_routes(route_data):
        # service == (’171’, [(’171’, ’1’, ’1’, ’59009’), ... , (’171’, ’2’, ’73’, ’59009’)])
        code = service[0] # 171
        directions = []
        route = []
        for stop in service[1]:
            # stop == (’171’, ’1’, ’1’, ’59009’)
           if stop[1] not in directions:
               directions.append(stop[1])
           route.append(stop[3])
        output.append((code, directions, route))
    return output
```

Each item in `output` will be a three-tuple of the `code`, the `directions` list and the `route` list, e.g.

```
output == [('171', ['1', '2'], ['59009', ..., '59009']), ... ]
```

You could consider making (some of) these values `int()` for further processing, or you can leave them as strings.

Comment: I am sorry but a tuple cannot have 3 parameter tuple(code, directions, route)

Comment: I can't run your code apparently when I return output the expected output is not the answer that I want. @jonrsharpe

Comment: If you explain more clearly the difference between the output from my code and your expectations, I can try to revise it. I have fixed the typo.

Comment: Ur code only return me [ ('184', ['1'], [['45009'... '45009']]) ]  My expected output is what I have stated above. [ ('106', ['1', '2'], [['43009', ... '43009']]),
     ('171', ['1', '2'], [['59009'...'59009]]),
      ('184', ['1'], [['45009'... '45009']]) ]

Comment: I have updated to show the full function - you may have the `return` statement indented too far

Comment: I think ur code is on the right track however the thing here is that how do u add in the ('106', ['1', '2'], [['43009', ... '43009']]) and ('171', ['1', '2'], [['59009'...'59009]]) ... I am struggling with this :)

Comment: It is align with for output = [] ... It did not work instead my python froze

Comment: is there something with your if loop ??

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "is there something with...". I don't have access to your `routes_data`, or to the `split_route` function, so I can't really test any further.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49489/discussion-between-user3398505-and-jonrsharpe)

Answer (score 0):

you return only `[(tuple([service_code] + [l] + [[curr_route]]))]` which is only one entry,
this is why you get only:

```
[('106', ['1', '2'], [['43009', ... '43009']])]
```

you need to store all entries in one list, say, `results` and append to it each entry in your loop, something like:

```
results.append(tuple([service_code] + [l] + [[curr_route]]))
```

and return:

```
return results
```